# JQuery detects hidden elements as visible and visible elements as hidden

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to call some functions based on whether elements are hidden or not. The strange thing is that similar conditions are working fine in the same code for two elements, save one.

I am doing something like this:

1. Clicking upon a link, hides the link and shows alternate link

> ```
>  $('#link1').click(function() {
>       $('#alt_link1').show();
>       $('#link1').hide();
>       $('#link2').hide();
>       $('#link3').show();
> ```

1. Based on the knowledge that links are hidden, I do something else

> ```
>  if ( $("#link1").is(':hidden') && $("#link2").is(':hidden') ) {
>     $('#link3').click(function() {
>     ..... }
>  }
> ```

Now having clicked link1, link1 and link2 should be hidden and link3 should be visible, which they actually are, as I can see in Firebug, but just in one case, JQuery detects the hidden elements in the condition as visible and visible as hidden. Now similar conditions work fine in the rest of the two cases that I have in the same code file, but strangely not with one other.

I tried doing this in many different ways to no avail. I am really stuck with this.

Comment: Rather than relying on :visible, I hide by adding the class 'hidden' and use .hasClass

Comment: seeing an example of what are you trying to achieve would be precious! Cause I think you're going the wrong way.

Comment: from my understanding `:visible` checks the `visibility` CSS property not `display`. When you fade in and out you are changing the Display property and not Visibility, hence your results.

Comment: Could you please post more context. Are the code snippet in the same function. Ie is the second snippet in the click handler for link1 if not what contextis it executed in?

Comment: @DavidBarker The `:visible` condition does checks the `display` property.

Comment: @PaulTomblin I don't quite get your suggestion. Can you give an example?

Comment: @RuneFS The code snippets are in the same context, under one if condition, if that helps. It is a fairly big file for me to put it out here exactly.

Comment: @Humming thanks for clearing that up :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following sequence, and assuming just one click binding (clicking only once), you shouldn't really be seeing problems with your original code:

```
$('#link1').one('click', function() {
      $('#alt_link1').show();
      $('#link1').hide();
      $('#link2').hide();
      $('#link3').show();
 if ( $("#link1").is(':hidden') && $("#link2").is(':hidden') ) {
    $('#link3').one('click', function() {
    ..... }
 }
});
```

Comment: Yes @sajawikio, as I mentioned the conditions work fine, in two cases in the same file, just not with one case, everything with them is exactly the same and yet.

Comment: What happens in the innermost click function? $('#link3').one('click', function() { .............

Comment: Nothing that can affect the conditions. It's a very long code, I have extracted what is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The if is evaluated immediately (ref your comment that they are in the same if body) if link one and two are hidden the event handler is attached if not there's no event handler attached for link3. If you later change the status of link1 and link2 that will not affect the result of your second snippet unless that is executed again

Comment: Yes link1 and link2 are hidden as I can confirm from the page source. I am doing the same thing with two others links in the same file with exactly similar conditions and they work fine.

Comment: It does not matter whether you can hide them but whether they are hidden when you execute the if. You are doing something slightly different in the case that works (or the timing is different) otherwise they would behave the same :)

Comment: @Humming simply set a break point at the if an evaluate whether the links are hidden or not when you reach that line

Comment: Yes, they are hidden when the if is executed, I can see it in Firebug.

Comment: @humming Then post a sscce. There are contradictions in what you've said so far. E.g you say the two pieces of code is on the same code level and that they are not (that one of them is executed after you click link1 if that's the case you're click event handler for link1 will not be attached yet and the links wouldn't have been hidden)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the inputs mate. I solved the issues. The code was just too large and many inter-dependent conditions to put here. I had to change many a things in the code file to get it to working, basically revamped the whole logic. Anyway, thanks again for your efforts!